# slide an image left or right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

How do you slide an image left/right using javascript? I want an image to slowly slide to the right. Do you use javascript's setTimeout function to gradually change element style's "left" value? Maybe jQuery has a function for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery sure does :)

There's a built in .animate() function: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Code example (slightly modified from the jQuery) is below and I've made a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/HRBkN/

CSS:

```
img.block {
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:50px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="left">left</button> <button id="right">right</button>
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" class="block" />
```

JS for absolute positioned img:

```
$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
});

$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
});
```

JS for relative/static positioned img:

```
$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"margin-left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
});

$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"margin-left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
});
```

Hope that helps:)

Comment: This example doesn't work :( Nothing happens in IE or chrome.

Comment: Just changed slightly. Check out the jsFiddle.

Comment: Also, to animate 'left' you need to have the img positioned absolutely with a 'left' value in css. If it is not positioned absolutely, use the following line instead `$(".block").animate({"margin-left": "+=50px"}, "slow");`. Note the use of `margin-left` :)

Comment: $("#right").click(function(){ ... } ) - this structure didn't work. Everything else worked. Thanks!

Comment: That function triggers the animation after an element with id="right" is clicked... :)

Answer (score 4):

jQuery has a built-in method called animate.

An example of using it:

```
$('#id').animate({
    left: 200
});
```

More: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULLN2/) that does it without `.animate()`. I haven't used `.animate()` but I'm gonna check it out after reading this post.

Answer (score 0):

I can sliding the image to left and right side with the following:

```
function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    if (n > x.length) 
    {
        slideIndex = 1
    }

    if (n < 1) 
    {
        slideIndex = x.length
    }

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
    {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }

    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```